# Passing view param while invoke_subrequest

Tags: python, pyramid

So I have 2 views and I want to setting a new `search_cache` while invoking view1 from view2. Can we do it in Pyramid?

```
@view_config(route_name="view1", request_method=["POST"], renderer="json")
def view1(self, search_cache=123):
    print('search_cache', search_cache)

@view_config(route_name="view2")
def view2(self):
    subreq = self.request.copy()
    subreq.path_info = "/view1"
    subreq.method = "POST"
    # Want to pass search_cache=456
    subreq.body = json.dumps({}).encode()
    response = self.request.invoke_subrequest(subreq)
```